# Invariance property of maximum likelihood estimator

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

I have a problem with the invariance property of MLE who say: (cfr. Casella-Berger Statistical Inference)

"If $\hat\theta$ is the MLE of the parametre $\theta$ and $g(\cdot)$ is a $1$-to-$1$ trasformation of $\theta$, then $\widehat{g(\theta)}=g(\widehat\theta)$".

My problem is that in the proof the book defines a new maximum likelihood function for $g(\theta)$:

"If $\eta=g(\theta)$ so $L^\star(\eta\mid\underline x):=L(g^{-1}(\eta) \mid \underline x)$ and so we can verify that $\sup_\eta\{L^\star(\eta\mid\underline x)\}=\sup_\eta\{L(g^{-1}(\eta)\mid\underline x)\}=\sup_\theta\{L(\theta\mid\underline x)\}$;"

but this thing does not prove the invariance, because the invariance follows by the new definition of $L^\star$. I think that the book has to show that $L^\star(\eta\mid\underline x)=g(L(\theta\mid\underline x))$ to prove the assertion, otherwise it can't talking about MLE for $g(\theta)$.

In fact, in this page there is something like my idea https://turing.une.edu.au/~stat354/notes/node69.html

Comment: But $L^\star(\eta) \ne g(L(\theta)).$ For example, suppose $X=\begin{cases} 1 & \text{with probability } \theta, \\ 0 & \text{with probability }1-\theta. \end{cases}$

And suppose $\eta= \theta^2.$ Then we have
$$
L^\star(\eta=0.04) = L(\theta = 0.2 ) = 1-0.2 \text{ if the observed value of $X$ is $0.$}
$$
and in general
$$
L^\star(\eta) = L(\sqrt\eta) = 1-\sqrt\eta = 1-\theta \text{ if the observed value of $X$ is $0.$}
$$
But $L^\star(\eta)=0.8 \ne 0.64 = (1-\theta)^2 = (L(\theta))^2. \qquad$

Comment: Thank you for the example. So,  would not it be better to say that "there is a way to extend MLE to a transformation of the parametre, and follows by its definition that maximum likelihood estimate of a transformation of the parametre is equal to the massimum likelihood estimate of the parametre"?

Comment: For example, if $X$ and $Y$ are IID with distributions dependent respectively by parametres $\theta$ and $\eta=\theta^2$ and let $L_X$ and $L_Y$ be their likelikood functions, then 

$ \hat{\theta^2}=\hat \eta = arg\sup_\eta L_Y(\eta)$ $=arg \sup_\eta $ $L_X^\star(\eta)$ $=(arg \sup_{\{\theta|\eta=\theta^2\}} L_X({\theta}))^2={\hat\theta}^2 $? Is this the hidden meaning of this property?

Comment: You shouldn't be think of two different random variables, but rather of two different parametrizations of a family of probability distributions. Note that in my comment above I considered only one random variable $X. \qquad$