# Jacobian factor: linear vs. non-linear transform of probabilty density and position of mean

Tags: probability-distributions, machine-learning

Consider a probability density $p_x(x)$ defined over a continuous variable x, and suppose that we make a non-linear change of variable using:

$$x=g(y)$$

so that the density transforms according to equation:

$$p_y(y) = p_x[g(y)]~|g'(y)|$$

(1) **Non-linear case**: By differentiating this equation, show that the location $\hat{y}$ of the maximum of the density in y is not in general related to the location of $\hat{x}$ of the maximum of the density over x by the simple functional relation: $\hat{x} = g(\hat{y})$ as a consequence of the Jacobian factor.

(2) **Linear case**: Show that in the case of a linear transformation, the location of the maximum transfrers in the same way as the variable itself.

(From TextBook: Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning, Christopher M. Bishop, 2006, exercise 1.4, page 58)

Answer (score 1):

Differentiating using the chain rule gives:
$$
p'_y(y)=p'_x(g(y))\cdot g'(y) \cdot |g'(y)| + p_x(g(y))\cdot\frac{\partial |g'(y)|}{\partial y}.
$$

At $\hat{x}$, the first term equals zero, because $p'_x(g(y))=0$ if $g(y)=\hat{x}$. However, because of the second term - which is in general nonzero **in the non-linear case** - $p'_y(y)$ does not equal to $0$ if $g(y)=\hat{x}$.

In the **linear** case, we have $\frac{\partial |g'(y)|}{\partial y}=0$, so the second term equals zero. Hence, in this case, we have $\hat{x}=g(\hat{y})$.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how (if at all) is this related to the [invariance property of the maximum likelihood estimator](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2716383)?